# Existance of multivariable limit

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We are asked to find whether the limit
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3y^3}{x^8+y^4}
$$
exists. I tried to find through the epsilon-delta definition but wasn't able to apply it successfully. So I tried to come up with a convergent sequence $(x_n)$ such that it converges to $(0,0)$ but $f(x_n)$ does not converge to a single point, thus establishing non-existence of the limit. But I wasn't able to come up with any such sequence.
When I checked on Wolfram-Alpha it showed the limit to be non existent. Can someone provide a proof of this or give example of a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $(0,0)$ such that such that $f(x_n)$ does not converge ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  MathJax commands aren't effective unless they're surrounded by `$` signs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By AM-GM inequality we have that

$$\frac{|x^3y^3|}{x^8+\frac{y^4+y^4+y^4}{3}}\leq \frac{3^{\frac{3}{4}}|x^3y^3|}{4|x^2y^3|} \leq |x|$$

thus the limit exists by squeeze theorem.